# Including JS file returns html content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am facing this problem, and i cannot figure it out. Its simple thing, i need to include my js file into a head. But in my page I've got error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' in ShopData.js:1** . So I've checked that file in chrome inspector, and i see that there is no JS content inside of it. It basically clone the html file and include it as js. How this can even happen and what is the solution? In ShopData.js is pure JS content, no includes or something. I've already checked permissions for that files and set it to read/write but no result, whole page is in domain hosting. Thanks for any advice.

```
   <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="ShopData.js"></script>
    </head>
```

JS File:

```
  var ShopID = 0;
  var Name = "";
  var City = "";
  var Street = "";
  var PostCode = "";
  var State = "CZ";
  var Longitude = "";
  var Lattitude = "";
  var Email = "";
  var Telephone = "";
  var Tittle = "";
  var Description = "";
  var Keywords = "";
  var Barbers;
  var OpeningHours;
  var ItemTypes;
  var Items;
  let ShopData = {};

    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://example.com/",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Screenshot of response[image]

Comment: Have you checked the actual file on your server, is that containing JS?

Comment: So...what file is the html above actually saved in? Is there some other content on there which could be causing this issue? How is this related  to php? And what's the content of shopdata.js really? This makes no obvious  sense unless there's something  else going on. You'll need to provide  us with  a [mre] of the issue before we can do much more than guess.

Comment: Yes, i can provide this file here too, its pure js, but for sure give me a sec.

Comment: script src is wrong, server tries to deliver a 404 page.

Comment: @ChrisG Both files are in the same folder.

Comment: Does it work on your localhost? Did you check with your hosting provider?

Comment: This has nothing to do with HTML or JavaScript. Your server delivers the pages, so the problem is somewhere on the server-side.

Comment: @brombeer I've checked that and on localhost its seems fine.

Comment: I'd suggest you to retag the question with your server (Apache?) (remove [javascript] and [html]), and add some details about this "_domain hosting_". Is it a web hotel, where the server configs and PHP are shared? Do you have .htaccess files? Can you access to httpd.conf?

Comment: Where in the root folder are the files hosted? And where is the domain pointing to? That `web` folder is making me suspicious. Still, if the main HTML and script are in the same folder, having just the filename as `src` should work in general. (also note that not just the website is broken, your HTML is, too. You need `<!doctype html><html><head>...</head><body>...</body></html>`)

Answer (score 0):

This file isn't valid JavaScript so it will give that error:
https://barber.minuto.cz/web/ShopData.js

Also it seems to give that response no matter which URL you type in:
https://barber.minuto.cz/web/asdfasdf

Also you may want to make it so everyone can't login here since it is out in public now:
https://barber.minuto.cz